# Solr getting stopped abruptly

Tags: solr, solr4

I am using Solr-4.3.1 on Ubuntu machine and it is running on default jetty server. Recently, I have observed that it gets shut down abruptly. I cant find any exception or error or warning message in the logs. Following are the logs:

> org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server; Graceful shutdown
>   SocketConnector@0.0.0.0:8983
>
> INFO  - 2013-10-16 15:05:15.091; org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;
>   Graceful shutdown
>   o.e.j.w.WebAppContext{/solr,file:/home/abhijeet/project/demo/Demo/solr-4.3.1/example/solr-webapp/webapp/},/home/abhijeet/project/demo/Demo/solr-4.3.1/example/webapps/solr.war
>   INFO  - 2013-10-16 15:05:16.093; org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer;
>   Shutting down CoreContainer instance=2137222734
>
> INFO  - 2013-10-16 15:05:16.236; org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore;
>   [collection1]  CLOSING SolrCore org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore@9f07597
>
> INFO  - 2013-10-16 15:05:16.244;
>   org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2; closing
>   DirectUpdateHandler2{commits=9,autocommit
>   maxTime=15000ms,autocommits=0,soft
>   autocommits=0,optimizes=1,rollbacks=0,expungeDeletes=0,docsPending=0,adds=0,deletesById=0,deletesByQuery=0,errors=0,cumulative_adds=0,cumulative_deletesById=0,cumulative_deletesByQuery=0,cumulative_errors=0}
>
> INFO  - 2013-10-16 15:05:16.245; org.apache.solr.update.SolrCoreState;
>   Closing SolrCoreState
>
> INFO  - 2013-10-16 15:05:16.246;
>   org.apache.solr.update.DefaultSolrCoreState; SolrCoreState ref count
>   has reached 0 - closing IndexWriter
>
> INFO  - 2013-10-16 15:05:16.246;
>   org.apache.solr.update.DefaultSolrCoreState; closing IndexWriter with
>   IndexWriterCloser
>
> INFO  - 2013-10-16 15:05:16.330; org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore;
>   [collection1] Closing main searcher on request.
>
> INFO  - 2013-10-16 15:05:16.332;
>   org.apache.solr.core.CachingDirectoryFactory; Closing
>   NRTCachingDirectoryFactory - 2 directories currently being tracked
>
> INFO  - 2013-10-16 15:05:16.352;
>   org.apache.solr.core.CachingDirectoryFactory; looking to close
>   /home/abhijeet/project/demo/Demo/solr-4.3.1/example/solr/collection1/data
>   [CachedDir<>]
>
> INFO  - 2013-10-16 15:05:16.352;
>   org.apache.solr.core.CachingDirectoryFactory; Closing directory:
>   /home/abhijeet/project/demo/Demo/solr-4.3.1/example/solr/collection1/data
>
> INFO  - 2013-10-16 15:05:16.352;
>   org.apache.solr.core.CachingDirectoryFactory; looking to close
>   /home/abhijeet/project/demo/Demo/solr-4.3.1/example/solr/collection1/data/index
>   [CachedDir<>]
>
> INFO  - 2013-10-16 15:05:16.353;
>   org.apache.solr.core.CachingDirectoryFactory; Closing directory:
>   /home/abhijeet/project/demo/Demo/solr-4.3.1/example/solr/collection1/data/index
>   INFO  - 2013-10-16 15:05:16.354;
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler; stopped
>   o.e.j.w.WebAppContext{/solr,file:/home/abhijeet/project/demo/Demo/solr-4.3.1/example/solr-webapp/webapp/},/home/abhijeet/project/demo/Demo/solr-4.3.1/example/webapps/solr.war
>
> INFO  - 2013-10-16 15:05:16.588;
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ShutdownThread; shutdown already
>   commenced

Comment: I have increase the allotted memory for solr jetty server with following command java -jar -Xmx 512M start.jar

Comment: I am running analogous problem, though I start with command "java -jar -Duser.timezone=GMT -Xmx4096M start.jar &" (on ubuntu). I have 7.5 million documents and Solr just shuts down "gracefully" after random delta import, which is run every 5 minutes and takes ~30 seconds to complete. Server has ~14.5 gb RAM. I have also tried allocating 6gb, issue still persists.